# org.encog.EncogError: Must have at least one output for feedforward

Tags: java, encog

I am trying to research on one topic and I am using Encog Library for JAVA.

I am having following issue

```
org.encog.EncogError: Must have at least one output for feedforward.
at org.encog.ml.factory.method.FeedforwardFactory.create(FeedforwardFactory.java:70)
at org.encog.plugin.system.SystemMethodsPlugin.createMethod(SystemMethodsPlugin.java:133)
at org.encog.ml.factory.MLMethodFactory.create(MLMethodFactory.java:104)
at org.encog.ml.model.EncogModel.createMethod(EncogModel.java:366)
at org.encog.ml.model.EncogModel.fitFold(EncogModel.java:190)
at org.encog.ml.model.EncogModel.crossvalidate(EncogModel.java:285)
at org.encog.examples.guide.classification.Classification.run(roadClassification.java:126)
at org.encog.examples.guide.classification.Classification.main(roadClassification.java:188)
```

My Files is as below

```
public class Classification {


private String tempPath;

public void run(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Download the data that we will attempt to model.
        System.out.println("Read File");

        File File = new File("E:/xyz.csv");
        // Define the format of the data file.
        // This area will change, depending on the columns and 
        // format of the file that you are trying to model.
        System.out.println("Create source");
        VersatileDataSource source = new CSVDataSource(roadFile, false,
                CSVFormat.DECIMAL_POINT);
        VersatileMLDataSet data = new VersatileMLDataSet(source);
        data.defineSourceColumn("abc", 0, ColumnType.continuous);
        data.defineSourceColumn("def", 1, ColumnType.continuous);
        data.defineSourceColumn("ghi", 2, ColumnType.continuous);
        data.defineSourceColumn("jkl", 3, ColumnType.continuous);
        data.defineSourceColumn("mno", 4, ColumnType.continuous);
        System.out.println("Create output column");
        // Define the column that we are trying to predict.
        ColumnDefinition outputColumn = data.defineSourceColumn("Prediction", 5,
                ColumnType.nominal); 
        System.out.println("Map the prediction column to the output of the model, and all other columns to the input.");

        data.defineOutput(outputColumn);
        // Analyze the data, determine the min/max/mean/sd of every column.
        System.out.println("Start Analysis");
        data.analyze();
        System.out.println("End Analysis");

        data.defineSingleOutputOthersInput(outputColumn);


        // Create feedforward neural network as the model type. MLMethodFactory.TYPE_FEEDFORWARD.
        // You could also other model types, such as:
        // MLMethodFactory.SVM:  Support Vector Machine (SVM)
        // MLMethodFactory.TYPE_RBFNETWORK: RBF Neural Network
        // MLMethodFactor.TYPE_NEAT: NEAT Neural Network
        // MLMethodFactor.TYPE_PNN: Probabilistic Neural Network
        System.out.println("Create TYPE_FEEDFORWARD neural network as the model type");
        EncogModel model = new EncogModel(data);
        model.selectMethod(data, MLMethodFactory.TYPE_FEEDFORWARD);

        // Send any output to the console.
        model.setReport(new ConsoleStatusReportable());

        // Now normalize the data.  Encog will automatically determine the correct normalization
        // type based on the model you chose in the last step.
        System.out.println("Now normalize the data");
        data.normalize();

        // Hold back some data for a final validation.
        // Shuffle the data into a random ordering.
        // Use a seed of 1001 so that we always use the same holdback and will get more consistent results.
        model.holdBackValidation(0.03, true, 1001);

        // Choose whatever is the default training type for this model.
        model.selectTrainingType(data);

        // Use a 5-fold cross-validated train.  Return the best method found.
        MLRegression bestMethod = (MLRegression)model.crossvalidate(3, true);

        // Display the training and validation errors.
        System.out.println( "Training error: " + EncogUtility.calculateRegressionError(bestMethod, model.getTrainingDataset()));
        System.out.println( "Validation error: " + EncogUtility.calculateRegressionError(bestMethod, model.getValidationDataset()));

        // Display our normalization parameters.
        NormalizationHelper helper = data.getNormHelper();
        System.out.println(helper.toString());

        // Display the final model.
        System.out.println("Final model: " + bestMethod);

        // Loop over the entire, original, dataset and feed it through the model.
        // This also shows how you would process new data, that was not part of your
        // training set.  You do not need to retrain, simply use the NormalizationHelper
        // class.  After you train, you can save the NormalizationHelper to later
        // normalize and denormalize your data.
        System.out.println("Loop over entire dataset.");
        ReadCSV csv = new ReadCSV(roadFile, false, CSVFormat.DECIMAL_POINT);
        String[] line = new String[4];
        MLData input = helper.allocateInputVector();
        int threshold = 50,count=0;
        float error=0,accuracy=1;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while(csv.next()) {
            if(count >=threshold){
                break;
            }
            count++;

            line[0] = csv.get(0);
            line[1] = csv.get(1);
            line[2] = csv.get(2);
            line[3] = csv.get(3);
            String correct = csv.get(4);
            helper.normalizeInputVector(line,input.getData(),false);
            MLData output = bestMethod.compute(input);
            String chosen = helper.denormalizeOutputVectorToString(output)[0];

            result.append("\n"+Arrays.toString(line));
            result.append(" -> predicted: ");
            result.append(chosen);
            error = (Float.valueOf(correct)) - (Float.valueOf(chosen));
            result.append("(error: "+error);
            result.append(")");
            accuracy*=error/100*count;

        }
        result.append("\naccuracy in (%) :"+accuracy);
        System.out.println(result.toString());
        // Delete data file ande shut down.
        //roadFile.delete();
        Encog.getInstance().shutdown();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    roadClassification prg = new roadClassification();
    prg.run(args);
}
}
```

Here you can see I have written both statements

```
 data.defineOutput(outputColumn);
 data.defineSingleOutputOthersInput(outputColumn);
```

Even I added the line

```
  VersatileMLDataSet data = new VersatileMLDataSet(source);
  data.getNormHelper().getOutputColumns().add(outputColumn);
```

But still it gives this error.

Comment: Can you try removing all other lines where you try to define the output column except:
data.defineSingleOutputOthersInput(outputColumn);